# Flask-Sqlalchemy create views with postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using a Flask-Sqlalchemy postgres database model with the following style:

```
class User(db.Model) // Holds the users
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Track(db.Model) // Holds racing tracks
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

class Record(db.Model) // Hold users records on tracks
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    track_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("map.id"), primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

My goal now would be to create a view which holds all Tracks completed by Users. In plain PostgresSQL it would look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW OR REPLACE user_tracks_finished AS
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, track_id 
FROM record;
```

The User model would look something like this:

```
class User(db.Model) // Holds the users
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    finished_tracks = db.relationship(...)
```

I can not any way to create views with the flask-sqlalchemy module. There is a sqlalchemy-views module, which I can not get to run in my flask app. Anybody got a good idea on how to model something like this? Any help ist appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done with SQLAlchemy-Utils: https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy-Utils/

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_view

class UserFinishedMaps(db.Model):
    __table__ = create_view(
        name="user_finished_maps",
        selectable=select([Record.user_id, Record.map_id]).group_by(
            Record.user_id, Record.map_id
        ),
        metadata=db.metadata,
    )
```